# How to convert Debian Packages (.gz) file to JSON or XML

Tags: php, centos, debian, deb

I'd like to convert Debian Packages file to JSON or XML.
The Debian's packages file: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian9.13/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz

I've tried to convert via [dctrl2xml](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dctrl2xml.1.html), it works perfectly, but it only avaliable in Ubuntu. My environment is CentOS / PHP.

How to convert Debian Packages (.gz) file to JSON or XML via CentOS?
or parse it via PHP? I don' think it's a good idel.

Thank you.

Comment: You can download the source for that tool here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dctrl2xml/0.19 Then you can either try and build it on your non-Debian system, or see how it does what it does to build your own version.

Comment: Extracting the contents of the provided gz file shows a pretty well-structured file format blocks of keys and values, with blocks separated by blank lines. I think it would be pretty easy to parse.